# Solution curve for three-variable differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that the functions $F(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ and $G(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ are integrals of the system of equations $dx/dt=y-z, dy/dt=z-x, dz/dt=x-y$, i.e. on any solution curve $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ these functions are constant. Interpret the result geometrically.

We have $dF/dt=dx/dt+dy/dt+dz/dt=(x-y)+(y-z)+(z-x)=0$, so $F(t)$ is constant.

Also, $dG/dt=2xdx/dt+2ydy/dt+2zdz/dt=2x(y-z)+2y(z-x)+2z(x-y)=0$, so $G(t)$ is constant.

But how can I interpret the result geometrically? I'm not even sure which geometric setting I should be looking at.

Comment: What does $F(x,y,z) = 0$ describe? What does $G(x,y,z) = 0$ describe? What does their intersection look like?

Comment: @copper.hat $F(x,y,z)=0$ is a plane passing through point $(0,0,0)$. $G(x,y,z)=0$ happens only at point $(0,0,0)$. So their intersection is the point $(0,0,0)$. How does that help?

Comment: My apologies, I meant equal to a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The ODE is the red coil , parallel to that is the green hexagon F, finally a scalar field for G.